# Infinite loop in integer data validation

Tags: java, validation

```
    boolean validator = true;
    int userMembers = 0;

    while(userMembers > 8 || userMembers < 1)
    {

        while(validator)
        {
            try
            {   
                System.out.println("How many members of the band? ");
                userMembers = input.nextInt();
                validator = false;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please user proper syntax");


            }
        }   

        validator = true;
    }
```

This is a problem I've been having for the last few hours. No matter what I do, I simply cannot force the while loop to actually ask the `userMembers = input.nextInt();` twice or more. It just runs in an infinite loop. This happens if I enter anything besides integer. Can someone please explain why this is not working or just give me a not over complicated solution?

Comment: To gain a better idea as to how your code is running, have you tried adding breakpoints within your IDE and stepping through the code? This should point out where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `input.nextLine ();` to your catch block, to consume the rest of the current input line.